# "ORA-01012" error message when trying to connect to an Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle10g, odp.net

Using C# and Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP) I made a long query to the database, then I end the connection on the server side using TOAD. After that, the subsequent calls to the database, even creating a new OracleConnection object, throw the following error:

```
ORA-01012: not logged on
Process ID: xxx
Session ID: yyy Serial number: zzz
```

Where Process ID and Session ID are the identifiers I used to end the connection.

It seems like when I end the connection to the Oracle database on the server side, the broken connection is returned to the connection pool. And when the C# client code (using ODP) opens a new connection, the broken connection that was returned to the connection pool may be retrieved.

Any ideas on how to fix this behaviour?

BTW I'm using Oracle client 10

Comment: Why kill the connection in TOAD?  Why not handle the close in C#?

Comment: @Limey All of this happens due to an application making bussines inteligence queries in an OLTP DB instead of an OLAP DB (something I can not change, at least not now). So, sometimes despite of the long process the user do not use the " Cancel option" througth the application hoping that the system returns the data he is waitig for, and that's why the DBA kill the session and the application becomes unresponsive.

Comment: So it seems that your real problem is that your query runs to long.  Have you looked at improving it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting to true the "Validate Connection" property in the connection string.

you can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B14164_01/featConnecting.htm#i1006393)

As a warning I quote the Oracle docs.

> The Validate Connection attribute validates connections coming out of
>   the pool. This attribute should only be used when absolutely necessary
>   because it causes a server round-trip to the database to validate each
>   connection right before it is provided to the application. If invalid
>   connections are uncommon, developers can create their own event
>   handler to retrieve a new connection, rather than using Validate
>   Connection. This generally provides better performance.

Comment: thanks !!! , working fine . If you dont mind could you please let me what exactly difference when you add `Validate Connection=true;` in connection `string web.config` ?