# C# ORA-01012: not logged on

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, oracle12c

I've made the connection to the Oracle DB in my .net Core API project

I use [this driver](https://github.com/ericmend/oracleClientCore-2.0) for connection to Oracle

My code:

```
connection.Open();

using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  cmd.CommandText = "MyPackage.SP";
  cmd.Parameters.Add(DbParam(cmd, "id", OracleType.Number, 1));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(DbOutParam(cmd, "out_key", OracleType.VarChar, 1024));

  try {
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    result = cmd.Parameters["out_key"].Value.ToString();
  } catch (OracleException oe) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("OracleException: {0}: {1}", Tool.GetCurrentMethod(), oe.Message);
  }

  connection.Close();
}
```

My connection string:

```
Data Source = ORACLE-DEV:1521/pdb;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user; Password=password;
```

Sometimes the connection disappears, and after I've got for all connections one exception:

```
ORA-01012: not logged on
Process ID: x
Session ID: y Serial number: z
```

I've already read [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022111/ora-01012-error-message-when-trying-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database) but there is a user solved the problem by setting to true the "Validate Connection" and also stay warning

> As a warning, I quote the Oracle docs.
>
> The Validate Connection attribute validates connections coming out of
>   the pool. This attribute should only be used when absolutely necessary
>   because it causes a server round-trip to the database to validate each
>   connection right before it is provided to the application. If invalid
>   connections are uncommon, developers can create their own event
>   handler to retrieve a new connection, rather than using Validate
>   Connection. This generally provides better performance.

I want to know what to do after catch exceptions like that and how to do reconnect automatically

```
try {
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} catch (OracleException oe) {
  Console.Out.WriteLine("OracleException: {0}", oe.Message);
  if (oe.Code == -1012) {
    // put your code here
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version Oracle?  You should add a tag for the version in addition to the Oracle tag. On recent versions, you can look at the diagnostic destination for the `tnslsnr` and `lsnrctl` -- on Linux look at `/u01/app/oracle/diag/` subdirectories `tnslsnr` and `lsnrctl`

Comment: @MarkStewart Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Personally I would concentrate on why the connection is closing.  Can you try using an official Oracle driver directly and see if it gives the same results?

Comment: Have you seen this: [Getting Started with ODP.NET Core](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html). Recommended driver to Oracle database for .net Core is: `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't retry executing the query after an exception has been caught, that solution can make your application potentially slow and unstable.

Your code seems simple enough to be working using the official driver so why using that unofficial driver your are using?

Try with the latest Oracle driver for .NET core:

First, remove the current driver, then install it using NuGet or the NuGet console:

```
Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core -Version 2.18.3
```

Comment: I used unofficial driver because when I've started to write my project - official driver was not realised

Comment: Should be easy to replace though, the syntax is the same, just replace the library using NuGet ;)

Comment: I have problems with Types, Before I use OracleType now I have to use  OracleDbType and there is no OracleType.Number. I've tried to use OracleDbType .Int32 but I've got exception Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Comment: That is a different question, if you post your code in a new question and send me the link I can take a look...

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it. Good answer

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, you could try something like the following (simple example):

```
var attempt = 0;
while (attempt < 2) 
{
   try {
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      break;
   } catch (OracleException oe) {
      Console.Out.WriteLine("OracleException: {0}", oe.Message);
      if (oe.Code == -1012) {
         connection.Open();
         attempt++;
      }
   }
}
if (attempt == 2) {
  // you have a problem!
}
```

This will try and if its closed, open the connection and try again.  Unsure what would happen though if something else is closing this connection - you would need to handle that appropriately outside the loop.

However this is merely hiding the underlying issue.